# numpy array prod vs multiply list items

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do multiply items of a list.
I did it by numpy and python loop the results are different.

would you please tell me what is the problem?

Numpy code

```
import numpy as np
a= [5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 4, 8, 9, 5]
print (np.prod(a))
>> 2039787520
```

python code without numpy

```
a= [5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 4, 8, 9, 5]
k=1
for i in a:
    k*=i
print (k)
>> 23514624000
```

**Another case:**

Numpy code

```
a= [4, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2, 8, 4, 8, 9]
import numpy as np
print (np.prod(a))
>> -579076096
```

without numpy

```
a= [4, 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 8, 2, 8, 4, 8, 9]
k=1
for i in a:
    k*=i
print (k)
>> 3715891200
```

**Question:** why at the second case the result is minus and different?

Comment: I get both to produce the same result, 23514624000

Comment: @Sheldore: You're probably on Linux, or some other platform where C long is 64-bit.

Comment: @Sheldore I use windows 10

Comment: `['4', '7', '6', '5', '4', '5', '6', '8', '2', '8', '4', '8', '9']`. These are strings

Comment: @Sheldore I corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python ints are arbitrary-precision. NumPy dtypes aren't; the default integer dtype in NumPy corresponds to C long, which is 32-bit on your platform. A computation that requires numbers too large for a C long will overflow.

You can specify a larger dtype to store larger numbers, but you can't store arbitrarily large numbers.

No overflow:

```
In [2]: numpy.prod([5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 4, 8, 9, 5], dtype='int64')
Out[2]: 23514624000
```

Still overflows:

```
In [3]: numpy.prod([10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000], dtype='int64')
Out[3]: 2003764205206896640
```

Comment: Thanks Now it works. is there any default setting to set it dtype='int64' for numpy?  I wanted to solve a problem I used prod and it gave me some numbers without any error. How should I know when it needs to add dtype='int64' ?

Comment: @Rezaenergy: There's no way to set a different default. You should pick your dtypes based on how big your numbers will need to be.

Comment: @rezaenergy I'd say, collectively, this kind of overflow has cost me maybe 2 weeks of work over the last few years on Windows. Don't needlessly waste space, but really bump it up your checklist when you have weird bugs.

Comment: @roganjosh I wanted to solve https://projecteuler.net/problem=8. I used numpy the final result (max number) wasn't correct. I was lucky that I had the goal number. I am thinking If it was a result of a predictive machine what would happen!?

Comment: I opened https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13369 and hope they will add some error or warning

Comment: @rezaenergy it does happen. The insidious ones are lost in my 500K loops in heuristics when I find the problem doesn't converge. The overflow is tough to catch in that case, you just see something is stopping convergence and suspect a logic error. All I'm saying is keep this issue well in mind, especially if you're on Windows.

Comment: @rezaenergy it's a well-known issue and is documented on those methods. Silent overflows will be duped and, to my knowledge, there aren't plans to change it.